# C# regular expression to validate a string

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

I have atext file that contains a lot of records like this:

```
05/11/04+11:10PM+117+04+0218735793+0'00+00:01'51+TR+
```

or

```
05/11/04+11:10PM+117+04+0218735793+0'00+00:01'51+TR+
```

(without INCOMING)

I want to validate these lines and invalidate all other lines(empty lines or comment lines and corrupted lines.

- Is it OK to regular expressions for this purpose?
- If yes, what is the regular expression?

Thanks.

Comment: Mos def. We don't know if the various fields and delimiters are fixed or variable width, but, yes... this is a good candidate for regex validation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991264/regex-query-builder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't try to use a regex for all of it. For example, you have what looks like a date and a time in there, and a couple of other fields that could be times of some kind, which are tricky to do with regular expressions.

I'd handle this with

- [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) on `+`
- Check you have the right number of fields
- Check each field individually depending on what it represents, e.g.

  1. [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx)
  2. [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx)
  3. regular expression for 3 digits
  4. ...

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact` throws when the parse fails, if this is likely to happen (ie. erroneous records are expected) better to use `DateTime.TryParseExact`.

Comment: Ah, I missed that method. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
^\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\+\d\d:\d\d[AP]M\+[\d+':]+\+TR\+$
                                   ^^^^^^^^
```

I "cheated" in the marked section because I'm not sure exactly what's staying the same, but from the rest of the expression I think you should get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
var regexPattern = @"^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}\+\d{2}:\d{2}(?:AM|PM)\+\d{3}\+\d{2}" +
                   @"\+\d{10}\+\d'\d{2}\+\d{2}:\d{2}'\d{2}\+TR\+$"
```